# PHP - how to watch for cookie (every second or time interval)?

Tags: php, cookies, intervals, watch

I want to watch for cookie and if this cookie exist do somethink. I tried this :

```
while (true)
{
    sleep(1);
    if ($_COOKIE['name'])
    { 
       doSomethink(); 
    }
}
```

But this code really make execution to 'sleep'.

Is there a way to watch without stopping the execution?

Comment: increase the execution time in your php.ini or your page

Comment: How can you expect from php to monitor a thing in real time????

Comment: how often do you want to watch?

Comment: every 1-3 seconds. (i just want to catch a cookie when JS create it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is a browser activity, a better way to do this may be a javascript `setInverval()` with an ajax call to a php function.

Otherwise, I'd recommend running the PHP script via CRON. There's no other way that I know to run PHP asynchronously, which is probably what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I don't know what is ajax and for what is used but now i will start reading. If ajax can call PHP function from Javascript, many of my issuses will be solved :) thx

Comment: I recommend you use `jquery`, an 80k script that makes AJAX and javascript quite easy to work with. You're in for a bit of a learning curve, but once you get it, you'll love it.